# how to get a table value that inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am trying to get values from a table that lives inside an iframe using jquery but so far with no luck.

i have tried this code:

```
$('#childframe').contents().bind("dblclick", function() {
var code = $('#childframe').contents().find('.priceName').text();
alert(code);
return false; }):
```

but i am getting the text of the entire td for that column. because i am using gridview sap.net control i can't set the ID for that td and I am forced to define the CssClass to "priceName".

"childframe" is the ID for my iframe.

Comment: if you need more information I will be more than happy to provide, I didn't want to overflow the system with information

Comment: Are you attemping to get the first TD, or a specific TD?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET 4.0, take benefits of the ClientIDRowSuffix & ClientID's Predictable mode.

Comment: I am forced to use asp.net 2.0 because of my client's server. and i am trying to get the text from the specific td the I dblclick on.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the text for the element that is double clicked:

```
$('#childframe').contents().bind("dblclick", function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/K9P9q/30/

**EDIT**

If you're having a difficult time getting this to work, here's another suggestion (this assumes that you control that page being loaded in the iframe).

1. Do your click binding in the iframe itself. This should simplify the jquery binding code.
2. In your click handler function within the iframe, invoke a function on the parent and pass the text of the selected TD to the parent. Example below.

**jQuery inside iframe**

```
$('#[tableIdHere]').bind("dblclick", function() {
    parent.HandleTdDoubleClick($(this).text());
});
```

**Hander inside parent**

```
function HandleTdDoubleClick(txt)
{
    alert(txt);
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and got an error message:
 "object required"
on chrome the function doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does the error occur on dblclick or on load? This should work in Chrome (it does on jsFiddle). Post the code.

Comment: A link to what? the jsFiddle? Post your code, you probably have some incorrect syntax. Here's the jsFiddle link again (it's in the original post): http://jsfiddle.net/K9P9q/30/

Comment: I saw your example, but it's need to be inside an iframe, that's the main difficulty.

Comment: thank for you help, is the way above is the right way to insert the JavaScript function?

Comment: The solution I provided is a perfectly acceptable way of doing it.

Comment: thank you!
that's works fine the only change i did in your answer is removing the .contents() from the JQuery function above.